# Show battery percentage on macOS lock screen?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur

How can I show battery percentage on my Mac's log-in screen?

My menu bar normally shows batter percentage, I have the option enabled in System Preferences, but when I close my laptop lid and reopen it or lock my screen and have to log in again, I can't see the battery's percentage, just the icon.

Answer (score 3):

Since the release of Big Sur, there appears to be no option to show battery percentage on the login screen. One thing you could do is [submit feedback about this to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macbookpro.html), which I've done since I want the option show battery percentage on my computer's login screen as well. Hope this helps!

EDIT: While not the same as on the lock screen, you can display the battery percentage on your Mac's screensaver by using the free and open-source screensaver [Aerial](https://aerialscreensaver.github.io/). While not mentioned in the official documentation, the [creator has mentioned it as a feature on Github](https://github.com/JohnCoates/Aerial/issues/980), and I've been able to test and verify that the screensaver does actually have that feature.

If you can't upgrade to Ventura as [Daniel Ting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/484286/daniel-ting) suggests in another answer, this is probably the easiest option for you.

Answer (score 3):

The battery percentage has been added back to the lockscreen in macOS Ventura!